# Computing the probability that one Brownian motion is greater or equal then the other

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Let's define two independent Brownian motions $B_1(t)$ and $B_2(t)$. The both start at zero.

I would like to find the following probability
$$P \big( B_2(t) \ge B_1(t) \big).$$

How can it be computed?

I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: $P(B_2(t) \geq B_1(t))=P(B_2(t)-B_1(t) \geq B_1(t)-B_1(t))=P(B_2(t)-B_1(t) \geq 0)=P(B_1(t) \geq 0) = \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $B_2 - B_1$ and $B_1 - B_2$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Can you provide some more tips, please?